# How to write option value as a input value from dynamically generated options using ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have this following html with a select drop-down which contains dynamically generated options from php and input fields.I want that, when  user selects any option of select then that option value will be pass into that input field.

[image]

here is my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;" >Loan Name:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-5">
      <select  class="form-control "  id="list" onchange="autolist(this.value)" >
      </select>     
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-sm-3"   >Loan ID:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lid"  placeholder="Loan ID Ouput">               
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JQuery Ajax  code:

```
<script>
   //It will called when ever select is clicked
   $(function autolist(selectedValue)
    {
       //This ajax call will bring the dynamically generated options from php
      $.ajax({
       url: 'employee_loan.php',
       success: function(data) {
           $('#list').html(data);       
       }
      });  

   //here i am trying to pass selected option value into that input field
    $("#lid").val(selectedValue);
   });
</script>
```

the option tag were correctly generated from php.The problem i got, whenever i try to select any option then it shows error on browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: autolist is not defined
```

I think, `onchange="autolist(this.value)"` is returning value before dynamically generated options from php Or parameter `this.value` is getting the value.I am not sure.I saw similar post, but could not solve this type of situation.Please help my with your clear explanation on whtat  exactly went wrong in this code and how to fix this.please let me know for any further information.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this:

```
onchange="autolist(this.value)"
```

And try with this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.form-group').on('change', '#list', function() {
        if ($(this).val != 0) {
            $('#lid').val($(this).val());
        } else {
            $('#lid').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

What this script does?

Attach an event handler on the `#list` element on change event. This is why you do not use inline javascript on your select element.

(That is not so lucky when you mix jQuery and javascript. And in this way, you can controll all your javascript things at one place, so you do not need to search later in your view files.)

When a change happens, it check, what is the value of your select list. If it is 0 (what is usually `---please select`), then set the Loan ID value to an empty string, so your placeholder will appears.

If it is not `0` then write the value of the option to the Loan ID field.

This is works with dynamically loaded data, since, I am using the `on` function.

```
$(function () {
    ....
});
```

is running on page load.

Comment: Nice idea @lolka_bolka.But `onchange="autolist(this.value)"` is actually doing 2 things [if you see my ajax code] doing both ajax call to generate options dinamically from php and also passing selected option value into `#lid`.so if i remove `onchange="autolist(this.value)"`  then how the ajax call generate options dinamically from php? thanks .nice explanation  btw

Comment: Thanks  @lolka_bolka. I got it correct by following your suggestion, i removed `onchange="autolist(this.value)"` modify my code like this: `$(function () {

$.ajax({
       url: 'employee_loan.php',
       success: function(data) {
           $('#list').html(data);       
       }
      });  

    $('.form-group').on('change', '#list', function() {
        if ($(this).val != 0) {
            $('#lid').val($(this).val());
        } else {
            $('#lid').val('');
        }
    });
});`

Comment: Thanks @lolka_bolka. can you also that.as you can the ajax is call each time to generate options dinamically from php.But if i got all generate options once, then i don't need to get it back again from php.i guess you understand what i am saying.so is there any way to prevent such redundant. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user5005768 Yes, put your ajax code outside of the `$('.form-group').on('change', '#list', function() {`. It will be called once on document load, but not on change. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$(function` with `function`

And replace `});` with `}`

so that the function will look like

```
<script>
   //It will called when ever select is clicked
   function autolist(selectedValue)
    {
       //This ajax call will bring the dynamically generated options from php
      $.ajax({
       url: 'employee_loan.php',
       success: function(data) {
       $('#list').html(data);       
       }
      });  

   //here i am trying to pass selected option value into that input field
    $("#lid").val(selectedValue);
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your js like this

```
<script>
   //It will called when ever select is clicked
   function autolist(selectedValue) {
      //This ajax call will bring the dynamically generated options from php
      $.ajax({
       url: 'employee_loan.php',
       success: function(data) {
           $('#list').html(data);       
       }
      });  

     //here i am trying to pass selected option value into that input field
     $("#lid").val(selectedValue);
   }
</script>
```